# Log file checksums

Tags: hash

I am told that you can tell if the log file (like from ripping a CD) has been modified by its checksum. How? How do you bypass this if you wanted to modify it?

Answer (score 2):

Files, like log files, can have a checksum or a hash calculated in order to determine if the file has been modified after the checksum or hash was made. This is simple, but effective.

What you do to check to see if there was modification is to run the checksum or hash process on the file and compare the results you get with the one that's stored. If they match, you have some assurance that the file has not been modified in the meantime.

There are 3 weaknesses in this approach:

1. The stored hash or checksum has to remain secure or else the person modifying the file can also update the hash/checksum.
2. The hash/checksum process needs to be relatively safe from 'collisions' - i.e. it should be very difficult to make changes to the file that do not result in the same hash/checksum.
3. The interested party has to go through the process of checking the hash/checksum.

Comment: Does this still apply if the person checking authenticity of the file doesn't know anything about the original sum? Where is the original sum stored?

Comment: Where the checksum is stored is up to the one making the checksum. How could someone check authenticity without a baseline to check against?

Comment: They can not. So If I create a modified file, how can they tell it was modified? They can not, correct?

Comment: In that case, it makes no difference whether a checksum was created or not... But I feel like I don't have all the details here .... I also feel like I'm enabling you to do something bad.

Comment: You are not enabling me to do something "bad"...think of it as lawful neutral. Primarily, the knowledge interests me, though I do have an application for it.

Comment: Look at it this way: a lot of sites that allow you to download their executable also display the MD5 hash of that file. You can see if the file has been modified before you run it. If you don't run the MD5 hash yourself, then you are none-the-wiser if someone had replaced the executable with a malicious one. The same would apply in your scenario. If they don't check, then you can make whatever changes you want.

Comment: But if the file existed only on my system before I uploaded it to them, it would be impossible for them to tell if it had been modified, correct?

Comment: Unless the file contains the checksum within itself and the log file is read by a reader that looks for that checksum. Like I said, I don't have all the details.

Comment: @random24234 - If they didn't have the file in the first place, it can never be modified from a previous version.  As far as they know, it's the first version.  Unless the application itself keeps some sort of versioning/document control.